# Get url parameters without splitting

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, dom, jstl

Is there somebody who can get the Parameters from the a href `class="popper"` without manipulating them (in javascript)

```
 <a href="./myservlet?AfspraakID=${cell.afspraakId}&Id=${cell.id}&KlantId=${cell.klant.id}" class="popper"</a>
```

The result i need is:

```
AfspraakID=${cell.afspraakId}&Id=${cell.id}&KlantId=${cell.klant.id}
```

I don't think it is that hard, but i cant find my solution(can you pls call the a href class to get the parameters from it)

thank you so much

Comment: So you do or don't want to use Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("a.popper").prop("href").split("?")[1]`